# How to implement coverflow with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a something like coverflow with recyclerview on android but i can't find the way to do it(already searched on google).

I know there is this library https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow but is no longer maintained and the publisher said that we could implement this behavior with recyclerview, can someone point me to the right direction? thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? I am searching for a similar solution.

Comment: I ended using viewpager and doing transformations with a custom adapter

Comment: @Baniares : how did you accomplished with Viewpager and transformations.. can you share code for same?

Comment: @Baniares can you post some code or roadmap as to what you did? I need to do the same thing. I'm sure you'll get lots of upvotes for the help too. :P